# .net core Razor pages with JQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to call a Razor Page Handler using JQuery AJAX. Here is the sample code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#SectionId").change(function () {
            var options = {};
            options.url = $(location).attr('href') + "/?SectionId=" + $("#SectionId").val() + "?handler=SelectByID";
            options.type = "GET";
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.success = function (data) {

            };
            options.error = function () {
                $("#msg").html("Error while making Ajax call!" + options.error.val);
            };

            $.ajax(options);
        });


    });
</script>
```

Razor Page cs code:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

    [BindProperty]
    public FileRecord FileRecord { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> UserList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedSectionId { get; set; }

    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGetSelectByID(string SectionId)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        //Prepare UserList
        UserList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<ApplicationUser> Users = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
        foreach (var item in Users)
        {
            string role = Enum.GetName(typeof(EmRoles), EmRoles.NormalUser);
            if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(item, role) && item.IsEnabled)
            {
                UserList.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = item.FullName,
                    Value = item.Id

                });
            }
        }

        //Sections
        ViewData["Sections"] = new SelectList(_context.Sections, "Id", "Name");

        //FileNOs
        ViewData["Files"] = new SelectList(_context.FileRegisters, "Id", "FileNo");

        //ViewData["ReceiverUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");
        //ViewData["SenderUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");
        return Page();
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        //Two File Records have to be created. One For Sender & One for receiver.
        FileRecord SenderRecord = new FileRecord
        {
            //create unique file id
            //FileId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            OutDate = DateTime.Now,

        };

        FileRecord ReceiverRecord = new FileRecord
        {
            //create unique file id
            //FileId = SenderRecord.FileId,
            InDate = SenderRecord.OutDate,

        };


        //Current logged-in user
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        SenderRecord.OwnerUserId = user.Id;

        //Receiver 
        ReceiverRecord.OwnerUserId = FileRecord.ReceiverUserId;
        ReceiverRecord.SenderUserId = SenderRecord.OwnerUserId;

        //Sender Record
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<FileRecord>(SenderRecord, "FileRecord", f => f.FileId, f => f.Remarks, f => f.Gist, f => f.ReceiverUserId))

        {
            //Receiver Record
            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<FileRecord>(ReceiverRecord, "FileRecord", f => f.FileId, f => f.Gist))

            {
                _context.FileRecords.Add(SenderRecord);
                _context.FileRecords.Add(ReceiverRecord);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
        }

        //If it reaches here. that means some error occurred.
        return null;

    }
}
```

The Issue is am not getting a call to Razor Page Handler defined above. If i skip the SectionId parameter passed-in & call only the handler. it is working fine. but it is not working when parameter is sent to the handler, default OnGet() is being called.

Help plz.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to append your `handler` parameter

```
options.url = $(location).attr('href') + "/?SectionId=" + $("#SectionId").val();
```

You also need to decorate the method with the HttpGet attribute

```
[HttpGet("GetSelectByID")]
public IActionResult OnGetSelectByID(string SectionId)
{
    return null;
}
```

Then your URL to call this method needs to be

```
http://localhost:xxxx/FileMovement/Create/GetSelectByID?SectionId=yyy
```

When you have more than one GET defined on a controller you must tag the additional GET methods with the HttpGet attribute and add a string to define the name of that method.

Comment: Thanks for  reply. href is https://localhost:xxxx/FileMovement/Create. Handler is in Create.cshtml.cs.  That said it's not working. Still getting call to default OnGet() method.

Comment: Then your URL should look like:
[http://localhost:xxxx/FileMovement/Create/OnGetSelectByID?SectionId=yyyy](http://localhost:xxxx/FileMovement/Create/OnGetSelectByID?SectionId=yyyy)

Comment: While debugging i could see the url as "https://localhost:44312/FileMovement/Create/?SectionId=x" .

Comment: Ged..its not working. Handler alone is getting called. but not with parameters...i am doing something wrong with these params

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more of your controller code where the OnGetSelectById method is defined please?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some additional changes for your controller

Comment: sorry for late reply.... Still not working. Am using Razor pages Web app VS 2017. your solution seems to be for WebAPI/MVC... In Razor Pages Web App, Handlers are used.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i was able to solve the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#SectionId").change(function () {
            var options = {};

            options.url = $(location).attr('href') + "?handler=SelectByID" + "&SectionId=" + $("#SectionId").val();;

            options.type = "GET";
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.success = function (data) {

            };

            options.error = function (data) {
                $("#msg").html("Error while making Ajax call!" + data.error.val);
            };

            $.ajax(options);
        });


    });
```

Everything was right except i have to use "&" in "&SectionId="

Comment: Nice Job! You helped me a lot)